# Vue v-if not reading variable

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, bxslider

I am using `Vue 2` on `Laravel 5.3` (using `bxslider` for carousel)
The following code gives me a single image (`img1`) slider.
If I remove `v-if`s it does give me 3 image (with `img1` `img2` `img3` in the slider).
Does `productChoiceSelected.img2` returns `true` if it is not `null` from the database?

EDIT (added full code of the component)

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
          <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img1">
        </li>
        <li v-if="productChoiceSelected.img2">
          <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img2">
        </li>
        <li v-if="productChoiceSelected.img3">
          <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img3">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        product:[],
        productChoiceSelected:[],
        productChoices:[]
      }
    },
    props:[
      'productId'
    ],
    mounted(){
      this.getProduct()
      this.getAllProductChoices()
    },
    methods:{
      getProduct(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$http.get('/getProduct/'+vm.productId).then((response)=>{
          vm.product = response.data.data.product;
          vm.productChoiceSelected = response.data.data.productChoiceDefault;
        });
      },
      getAllProductChoices(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$http.get('/getAllProductChoices/'+vm.productId).then((response)=>{
          vm.productChoices = response.data.data.productChoices;
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

EDIT #2
I guess it is because `productChoiceSelected.img2` is a url directory? it is `http://localhost:8000/img/products/1-2.bmp`

Comment: why don't you console.log to see what it returns?

Comment: @xhulio thanks for your response. Not sure how you exactly do that, but I checked with Vue devtool and it productChoiceSelected is defined with img1 img2 img3 under the component.

Comment: just for your information, when you want to see what any javascript returns or gets executed, just write on your script after the code to be executed `console.log(variable + 'or text');` and then you will see the result in the dev tools

Comment: @xhulio, thank you for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can figure out few issues in your code:

1. You need to have `img1` and these variables defined as these are to be set reactively to be used in vue templated.
2. You need to move `$('.bxslider').bxSlider({})` code in the updated section as this needs to be executed once you get the data updated from backend.

Following are code changes:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        productChoiceSelected: {
        img1:'',
        img2:'',
        img3:''
        }
      };
    },
    mounted(){
      this.getProduct()
    },
    updated(){
       $('.bxslider').bxSlider({});
    },
    methods:{
      getProduct(){
        var vm = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
          vm.productChoiceSelected.img1 = 'http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg'
//          vm.productChoiceSelected.img2 =  'http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg'
          vm.productChoiceSelected.img3 =  'http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg'

        }, 300)
      }        
    }
})
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwm75s4b/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for saurabh contribution above, as I am still unsure where the problem is, here is how I solve the problem by myself for you guys' reference.

Change in code:

```
      <template>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="bxslider">
              <li>
                <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img1">
              </li>
              <li v-if="img2">
                <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img2">
              </li>
              <li v-if="img3">
                <img :src="productChoiceSelected.img3">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
.....
.....
.....

        methods:{
          getProduct(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.$http.get('/getProduct/'+vm.productId).then((response)=>{
              vm.product = response.data.data.product;
              vm.productChoiceSelected = response.data.data.productChoiceDefault;
            if(vm.productChoiceSelected.img1){
              vm.img1 = true
            }
            if(vm.productChoiceSelected.img2 != null){
              vm.img2 = true
            }
            if(vm.productChoiceSelected.img3 != null){
              vm.img3 = true
            }
            });
          },
    ......
    ......
    ......
```